# Can we introduce line break (css) in map in react.js based on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array in which i am trying to introduce a line break every fourth element of array, so that every four elements are together while next line will contain next 4 elements and so on.

```
this.state.colors: ['red', 'brown', 'yellow', 'blue', 'black', 'pink', 'green', 'aliceblue', 
'gray', 'magenta', 'orange', 'violet','coral', 'white', 'olive', 'lightgreen']

 <ul className="colorsList">
  {this.state.colors.map((color, index) => (
      <div>
          <div className="flex">
              <div style={{ background: color, height: 20, width: 20 }}></div>
          </div>
          {(index === 3 || 7 || 11) && <br></br>}
      </div>
  ))}
 </ul>
```

Should look like..

```
[][][][]
[][][][]
[][][][]
```

here brackets indicate these color boxes with 20, 20 height and width.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use this condition

```
index % 4 === 0 ?  return : do your work
```

so the result will be =>

```
 <ul className="colorsList">
                    {this.state.colors.map((color, index) => (
                        <div>
                            <div className="flex">
                                <div style={{ background: color, height: 20, width: 20 }}></div>
                            </div>
                            {(index % 4 === 0 &&  <br />)}
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </ul>
```

Comment: The question is  not at all this.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. However, the answer is index % 4 === 0 
will give you the alternative of hardcode it like 
3 || 7 || 11 .etc 
I hope it helps you

Comment: That array should display 4 array elements together in horizontal plane than next 4 in another horizontal plane. Do u really think that by just using `index % 4 === 0 ` or `3 || 7 || 11` we can achieve that. No. we need flex or float to get them together. Now how we apply that flex or float is the real question, there brains is required, not in division, that's the minimum thing and there are dozens of ways to do that.

Comment: @TrickOrTreat
I understand, 
ok I think all that needed is pure CSS
check this code on code sandbox 
https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-mendeleev-j5lw7.

Answer (score 0):

I didnot want to involve javascript for this problem i came accross and wanted to do it with pure CSS. Here is my solution :)

```
this.state.colors: ['red', 'brown', 'yellow', 'blue', 'black', 'pink', 'green', 'aliceblue', 
'gray', 'magenta', 'orange', 'violet','coral', 'white', 'olive', 'lightgreen']

<ul className="colorsList">
                    {this.state.colors.map((color, index) => (
                        <div>
                            {(index % 4 === 0 ) ?
                                <div>
                                    <div style={{ clear: 'both' }}></div>
                                    <div style={{ background: color, height: 20, width: 20, float: 'left' }}></div>
                                </div>
                                :
                                <div style={{ background: color, height: 20, width: 20, float: 'left' }}></div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </ul>
```